# Solaris Home/End keys not working like Debian / Ubuntu

Tags: solaris

I'm using putty for connecting to a solaris system.

I'm just a user (no root access).  All what I know about the system is

> Oracle Corporation      SunOS 5.11      11.1    January 2014

My problem is comming from the keyboard settings.  The keys `insert/home/pageup/pagedown/end/delete` are all displaying `~` instead of moving the cursor like in Ubuntu.

I already tried lot of tricks found on internet but nothing is working.

`echo $TERM` gives `xterm` and putty is well configured with xterm.

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To support alternative key mappings you can use the GNU readline library's `inputrc` init file.

Each user can have their own `.inputrc` file in their home directory. Or use global `/etc/inputrc` to set it for all users.

---

To check the current key map, enter verbatim mode (`Ctrl-v`) followed by the key to map. This will prevent the `shell` from parsing and executing the key and provide the key sequence.

**E.g.**

```
Ctrl-v Home
^[[1~
```

The `^[` sequence is equivalent to the `[Esc]` key, so needs to be mapped as `e\`.

To test a new map use the `bind` command:

```
bind '"\e[1~": beginning-of-line'
```

Once this works, you can either add the `bind` command to your shell profile or add all the maps to your `.inputrc` file.

---

For **Debian / Ubunutu** based key mappings, add the following into your personal `~/.inputrc` file:

```
# for linux console and RH/Debian xterm
set meta-flag on
set input-meta on
set convert-meta off
set output-meta on
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line
# commented out keymappings for pgup/pgdown to reach begin/end of history
#"\e[5~": beginning-of-history
#"\e[6~": end-of-history
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
```

Then log in again or start a new shell.

Comment: I tried set -o vi. With home : the cursor go back 1 position on the last character and toggle it uppercase/lowercase. Another home : just toggle the last character.

Comment: I tried shift-home and shift-end : still get ~

Comment: What does `echo $SHELLOPTS` give you?

Comment: echo $SHELLOPTS
braceexpand:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor:vi
and (without set -o vi) 
echo $SHELLOPTS
braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor

Comment: Can you give me an example of where you would normally find the behaviour you expect?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.  Never used solaris, but with ubuntu I can use the home/end key to go to the begin/home of the command line.  And I can also use the left/right arrows keys and the the del key but here (with solaris) I have to use the backspace.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know... Please hold.

Comment: Solution attached.

Comment: @tweetysat : sorry forgot to tag you. I have updated the answer with your solution.

Comment: thanks for your solution but ... it's not working for me.  I didn't have a .inputrc.  So I created one with your content.  But now none of the 6 keys is working.  There is a change because no more ~ but nothing more is done.

Comment: Try `Ctrl-v` followed by the Home key to ensure it matches the setting: You should get `"^[[1~"` which equates to `"\e[1~"` (substituting the escape).

Comment: Yes, it gives me ^[[1~

Comment: And if you type `bash`, then enter text, do they still not work?

Comment: Same problem.  None of the keys is working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17916/discussion-between-geedoubleya-and-tweetysat).

Comment: @tweetysat - Do you want to accept my answer to prevent other users thinking it is not solved?